# Show hide <ion-slide> in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using `<ion-slide-box>` having 5 `<ion-slide>`. I want to hide last 2 ion-slides at first then want to show the 4th and 5th slides based on some condition.

I wrote `ng-show="false"` in 4th and 5th `<ion-slide>`. But it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: try `ng-if` it will work or provide your code

Comment: hey, thanks... it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-show` and `ng-hide` will only disable the field.

to make your requirement visible and not visible under certain condition try using `ng-if`.

For more information about [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) look in the document.

for getting the value show only when the condition is **true** try use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).